# How to analyse reading data with two word types and three types of dependent variables?

Tags: repeated-measures

In my study, I have one group encoding 2 different types of words (within subjects) and 3 different dependent measures namely recall, recognition, rating.

I think that I can conduct repeated measure analysis.
But I am confused about what should I write for factor name. I think I have one factor with two levels because all subjects encoded 2 different types of words in the same list.

Is that right?

And I defined three measure names to define DVs.Is that OK?

Comment: What do you mean by "one group"?  Is this just your sample of subjects?  Also, "2 different types of words" is ambiguous.   I'd reword your first sentence as "In my study, I have ??? subjects, each of whom encode ??? different words against three different measures.  The words are categorised into two types".  Or I may be wrong - the point is your first sentence is hard to understand.

Comment: sorry, didn't mean to sound rude - just to point out that it will be hard to answer the question until people are sure of the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more, it sounds like:

- You could perform three separate paired-samples t-tests (IV = encoding condition), one for each of the types of dependent variables.
- If recall, recognition, and rating are all on the same scale, then you could perform a $2 \times 3$ within subjects ANOVA. I can imagine that recall and recognition would both be accuracy measures, but you don't make clear what "rating" represents. I imagine it would be on a different scale and as such it would not make sense to combine it in an overall analysis with recognition and recall.

Answer (score 1):

If you have both recall and recognition data from a word list, you may be able to use a multinomial processing tree model, specifically the Chechile-Meyer model. But this depends on your exact design.

The Chechile-Meyer Task separates storage and retrieval processes in an elegant way. See the following publications:

- Chechile, R. A. (2004). [New multinomial models for the Chechile–Meyer
  task](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022249604000707). *Journal of Mathematical Psychology*, 48(6), 364–384.
  doi:10.1016/j.jmp.2004.09.002
- Chechile, R. A. (2010). [Modeling
  storage and retrieval processes with clinical populations with
  applications examining alcohol-induced amnesia and Korsakoff amnesia.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022249609000376)
  *Journal of Mathematical Psychology*, 54(1), 150–166. doi:10.1016/j.jmp.2009.03.006

To fit the model, you could use our R package MPTinR (on CRAN), see:

- Singmann, H., & Kellen, D. (in press). [MPTinR: Analysis of
  Multinomial Processing Tree Models in R](http://www.psychologie.uni-freiburg.de/Members/singmann/pubs/MPTinR_submitted/download). *Behavior Research Methods*.